# FCI with Alwayson Availability Group (Asymmetric Storage)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering

I am trying to setup a demo environment where I have a windows cluster with 3 nodes.
Node 1 will be standalone sql server and will be the primary replica. 
Node 2 and 3 will be in a Failover cluster instance(sqlclu1) and that will be the async secondary replica.

I have installed sql server as a clustered instance (Node 2 and 3) and
has a shared storage(E: drive) which is presented only to node 2 and 3 and which contains sql data files(by which I mean, the possible owner for this disk is only node 2 and 3 and also I have not connected the disk to Node 1).

I am stuck at the next step where I am trying to install a standalone sql server on node 1 for being the primary replica.  The issue is when I try to add a disk with the same name (E:) it is not letting me do that.  E:drive is just not available in the list when I create a new volume.

I am guessing I have stuffed up something and am wondering how Asymmetric Storage needs to be configured so that I can create disk with the same drive letter.

As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj215886.aspx

> Asymmetric Storage Two FCIs, one at each site on a single multi-site
>   WSFC, introduce considerations around how shared storage is handled.
>   Each FCI has its own shared storage. The nodes at the primary site
>   share storage among themselves to form a shared-storage FCI, and the
>   nodes at the DR site share storage among themselves to form another
>   shared-storage FCI. The storage on the primary site is not visible to
>   the nodes on the disaster recovery site and vice versa. This
>   arrangement of storage, where a cluster disk is shared between a
>   subset of nodes within a WSFC, is referred to as asymmetric storage.
>   Before the asymmetric storage capability, shared storage needed to be
>   visible to all the nodes in the WSFC (symmetric storage).  This
>   Windows Server enhancement is the key piece of functionality that
>   enables the FCI + AG solution architecture discussed in this white
>   paper. By enabling this functionality, you can combine the shared
>   storage solution (FCI) with the non-shared storage solution
>   (availability groups), in a single HA + DR solution. **Consequently,
>   this enhancement also enables you to use identical drive letters for
>   shared disk resources across data centers**.

Using sql server 2014 and windows 2012R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to create the drive through Server manager, when I create the drive through Drive Management it worked fine.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding it under another drive letter, and then changing the drive letter via Disk Management. [It's what was suggested by Microsoft during the CTPs.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/623866/denali-ctp1-sql-hadr-drive-letters-in-wsfc)

Comment: I was trying to create the drive through Server manager, when I create the drive through Drive Management it worked fine.